# How do we can run specific test case using gulp/Karma/Jasmin and angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, gulp

I have multiple files for test case in a folder and I want to run only one file, how can I do this?

Now I am giving like this:

`'test/**/*.spec.js'` in `karma.conf.js`

and the following code is in `gulpfile.js`-

```
gulp.task('test', function (done) {
    new Server({
        configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
    }, function () {
        done();
    }).start();
});
```

Here, **test** is my folder where all test case js files are present.

How can I specify one js file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Along with `configFile` you specify the options that will overwrite the ones from config file (e.g. `singleRun`).

So it has to be

```
gulp.task('test', function (done) {
    new Server({
        configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.js',
        files: ['test/some.spec.js'],
        singleRun: true
    }, function () {
        done();
    }).start();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

For this worked like a charm:

```
gulp test --specs path/file.spec
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use **fit** and **fdescribe** in order to run single testcase along with config mentioned, above